# How do I formulate a query using the Symfony Plugin DbFinderPlugin to count grouped by columns?

Tags: mysql, plugins, symfony1, count

I cannot figure out how to write the following query using the DbFinderPlugin 1.2.2 with Symfony and Propel:

```
SELECT species, COUNT(*) FROM Bird GROUP BY species;
```

[Here is the DbFinderPlugin page](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/DbFinderPlugin)

I am rather new to the plugin, and I do love it so far, but this query has so far stumped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you have to use withColumn to get the proper result:

```
$result = DbFinder::from('Bird')
    ->withColumn('count(Bird.Id)', 'total_birds')
    ->groupBy(species')
    ->find();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at DBFinder but it looks like the following should work

```
$result = DbFinder::from('Bird')->
  groupBy('species')-> 
  select(array('species', 'count(*) cnt'))->
  find();
```

Edited to change code

Comment: This returns me: "Unknown model class species". It seems that with() seems to want a model class and not just a column name. How do I specify just a column name?

Comment: my bad. with is for use with joins. if a join is not explicitly done, with will do one anyways. edited code above. I really couldn't find an easier way to do it in the docs, but it looks like it should work

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, now it gives me: "Calculated colums added with sfPropelFinder::withColumn() need an alias as second parameter".  I've tried adding aliases everywhere, but I'm just not sure what it's referring to in this situation.

Comment: I should have realized it would need an alias for the count. edited